# Ruby on Rails Decimal property validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, decimal

I have a business model with a decimal field. Its value must be between 0.00 and 999.99. So I have created a decimal field and add validations to the model.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

  validates :price, format: { with: /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/ }, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 1000 }

end
```

When I create the Order object with a decimal value which is greater than 1000 or less than 0, I get the error I expected and that's ok. I can see that 
"numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 1000 }" validations work as expected.

Howeber, when I try to create an Order object with a decimal value of 45.45554 or 45.45666, rails persists the object to the database with the price value of 45.45. I expect getting a format error, but it seems that
format validation doesn't work.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Any suggestions,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What is the precision of your price field?  Via the [docs](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#column-modifiers):

`precision` Defines the precision for the decimal fields, representing the total number of digits in the number.

I'm assuming price only has a precision of 2, and that's why it's getting rounded.

Comment: Yeap, price has a precision of 2. Assuming that I doesn't have a precision, format validation must work. However, either way, It doesn't work.

Comment: I would increase your precision, if you mean that you want to require a certain amount of decimals, that's another story, but I don't understand your use case.

Answer (score 1):

The value is converted to decimal by the setter. Which means that format validation will always pass.

If you need validate the format use `read_attribute_before_type_cast` in a custom validation.

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord

  validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than: 1000 }
  validates :price_format
  PRICE_REGEXP = /\A\d+(?:\.\d{0,2})?\z/.freeze

  private 
  def price_format
    unless read_attribute_before_type_cast('price') =~ PRICE_REGEXP
      errors.add('price', 'must match the correct format')
    end
  end
end
```